# How to send string array as a query parameter to WebAPI from C# http client

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

Backend of our application is exposing web api which accepts IEnumerable. Following is the example definition:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int? id = null, [FromUri]IEnumerable<string> category = null)
```

I am manually creating URL with query parameters as follows:

```
category=category1&category=category2
```

..and appending it to the actual URL to obtain the result.

Is there any better way of adding category list as a query parameter instead of manually creating url? What is the best way of passing a string array to an endpoint in the URI?

Comment: Try `/foo/id=123?category=category1&category=category2` (note `?` after `123`)

Comment: All the parameters in the endpoint are optional. I missed adding that. Please see the edit.

Comment: [one way](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/849034/Csharp-Web-API-HTTP-GET-with-a-Request-Body). Or you could do a post as you might hit the limit of 2048 characters. Or you could have a single parameter with a delimiter.

Comment: @lloyd: In the way you suggested, I will have to ask backedn team to change the endpoint as it has to accept parameters from header which is not currently possible.

Answer (score 3):

Just try like this;

```
/foo/Get?id=123&category=category1,category2
```

You can seperate array elements by using `comma(,)`.

Comment: Response is bad request

Answer (score 0):

I'm asuming you have the routes setup for WebAPI setup as defaults:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

you'll need to update your method signature to **include** `[FromUri]` on the `id`

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromUri]int? id = null, [FromUri]IEnumerable<string> category = null) {...}
```

This will allow the `id`to come from the Uri instead of the route data.

thus meaning if you do a get request to:

```
GET /api/foo?id=123&category=category1&category=category2
```

This should give you the expected values of

```
id = 123

category = ["category1", "category2"]
```

You'll also be able to do requests like:

```
GET /api/foo?category=category1&category=category2
```

and will give you the expected values of

```
id = null

category = ["category1", "category2"]
```

Comment: All parameters of the enpoint are optional. Please see the updated question. And the way you are suggesting is unfortunately not working.

Comment: @Ajinkya fixed up answer based on change question :-)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. As I have mentioned in my question for request `/foo/id=&category=category1&category=category2` the response is bad request.

Comment: In your example it's trying to convert `id=&category=category1&category=category2` in to a `int` this wont be possible - 400 Bad request

Comment: Parameter id is nullable int

Comment: You still can't convert that string to a nullable int.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is not there in the URL itself. Actual URL is `/foo/category=category1&category=category2`

Comment: you need a `?` ------